# Use SQL to Evaluate XML string broken into several rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have an application that stores a single XML record broken up into 3 separate rows, I'm assuming due to length limits.  The first two rows each max out the storage at 4000 characters and unfortunately doesn't break at the same place for each record.

I'm trying to find a way to combine the three rows into a complete XML record that I can then extract data from.

I've tried concatenating the rows but can't find a data type or anything else that will let me pull the three rows into a single readable XML record.

I have several limitations I'm up against as we have select only access to the DB and I'm stuck using just SQL as I don't have enough access to implement any kind of external program to pull the data that is there an manipulate it using something else.

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your data and a reproducible example? It would help others a lot in answering you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data, and desired results, we can only offer a possible approach.

Since you are on 2017, you have access to `string_agg()`

Here I am using ID as the proper sequence.

I should add that `try_convert()` will return a NULL if the conversion to XML fails.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(4000))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'<root><name>XYZ Co')
,(2,'mpany</')
,(3,'name></root>')

Select try_convert(xml,string_agg(SomeCol,'') within group (order by ID) )
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
<root>
  <name>XYZ Company</name>
</root>
```

> **EDIT 2014 Option**

```
Select try_convert(xml,(Select '' + SomeCol
                         From  @YourTable 
                         Order By ID
                         For XML Path(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
        )
```

**Or Even**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = ''

Select @S=@S+SomeCol
 From  @YourTable
 Order By ID

Select try_convert(xml,@S)
```

Comment: Thanks, John.  Unfortunately I was wrong about the version of SQL Server running on the back end.  I'm running SSMS 2017 but connecting to a SQL Server 2014 database.  I've updated the tag to correctly reflect that.  Thanks very much for the input though.

Comment: I should also mention that I did try this solution and only realized the back end was not 2017 when getting the result of 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.  Thanks again.

Comment: @LouisNegron See EDIT 2014 Option  (supplied two alternatives)

Comment: @LouisNegron Perhaps is help if you edit your question and supply a SMALL data sample

Comment: Thanks, John.  I did actually get your sample to work.  It was my own fault as I was trying to populate the insert with a select but I had my select in parentheses.  The first example for 2014 does get me a completed XML string so thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @LouisNegron Always happy to help  :)